# Calling Mp4Box.exe from .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell, command-line, mp4

Hello i am making a code for doing some editing on mp4 video using mp4box.exe

i want to execute this command line:

```
 "D:\Work\Me\CloudContentUpload\trunk\ContentUploading Current\bin\Debug\Mp4Box\Mp4Box.exe" -isma -inter 500 "C:\Users\Abdullah\Desktop\videoo\amr khaled - Asmaa_elmogeb\Asmaa_elmogeb(1).mp4"
```

This command executed successfully when i run it manually on command line

but i try to execute it with the following C# code:

```
    public string ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
            // and "/c " as the parameters.
            // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
            // and then exit.
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

            // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
            // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

            proc.Start();
            // Get the output into a string
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the command output.
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            return objException.Message;
        }
    }
```

the result returned is empty string !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call cmd for this.

You should call your program directly and pass in the arguments to the `Arguments` property of `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help .. It Worked Successfully